# Shorthand for multiple assignments in R

Tags: r

I have functions that load datasets that are pretty repetitive for cleaning data.

```
load_data = function(f){
  data = read.csv(f)
  data$x = (data$a - data$b)/1000
  data$y = (data$c - data$d)/1000
  data$z = (data$e - data$f)/1000
  data
}
```

Is there any syntactic sugar in R that can make this process less verbose?

The code works, there is no performance problem, but when you have to do the same operation dozens of times, it is less than optimal to modify.

Comment: `(data[c(TRUE, FALSE)] - data[c(FALSE, TRUE)])/1e3` maybe? You could insert it into `data` using `data[c("x", "y", "z")] <- `. Though it's not clear how many columns you really have there and etc. Your question isn't reproducible as is.

Comment: Using `data.table`: `data[, \`:=\`(x=(a-b)/1000, y=(c-d)/1000, z=(e-f)/1000)]`

Comment: It's not clear how you want it to be shorter? Do you want not having to type `data` multiple time? Use `attach` or `with`.

Comment: Factor out the common things into a function, create a list with the variant things, then do an `lapply`. That is how it is usually done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little more readable / less verbose:

```
load_data <- function(f){
    within(read.csv(f), {
        x <- (a - b) / 1000
        y <- (c - d) / 1000
        z <- (e - f) / 1000
    })
}
```